# How to use sdf element in gazebo 7.4

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to use the sdf class inside my program but it seems like in gazebo 7.4 class sdf is not present as i saw [here](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/7.1.0/classes.html), I looked at older version gazebo api also and i could clearly see this class in them like [here](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/1.6.3/classsdf_1_1SDF.html). So how can i use the sdf class in gazebo 7.4.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15117/how-to-use-sdf-element-in-gazebo-7.4/) by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 56 on 2017-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

SDFormat was moved into an independent [library](http://sdformat.org/) (since Gazebo 1.9, I [think](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-requests/627/use-external-sdformat-repository-gazebo_19/diff)) .

You can see the API documentation here:

http://sdformat.org/api

You can still use it in your Gazebo plugins and stand-alone programs, adding this header:

`#include <sdf/sdf.hh>`

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1